# Alternative for gammainv() Excel function?

Tags: excel, vba

I believe I'm encountering a problem with the gammainv function of Excel 2007. For some combinations of input parameters it returns the #NUM! error.

The gammainv function returns the inverse of the gamma cumulative distribution.

```
Syntax --> gammainv(probability,alpha,beta)
```

For example:

```
=gammainv(0.83,0.0977,25.849) '<-- gives this problem.
```

With the same alpha and beta, the problem arises also with probability= 0.84 and probability = 0.85 but not with all other 0.01 increment values between 0 and 1. This is an example, the problem also arises for other combinations of probability, alpha and beta. This example does work without problems when using matlab's `gaminv` function.

I believe the problem is related to this problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/215214

My question if there is a solution to this problem. I'm interested in:

- Some fix for this function in Excel 2007
- A VBA function that does the same, but without the problem.
- Any other lead to narrowing down the problem.
- Any workaround that will help me evaluate instances as the presented example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been trying it for a few minutes now, but haven't found anything yet. If you know your way around in this world, I'd very much like it if you'd post a link to such a function.

Comment: The original comment seems to have vanished. The suggestion was: Google for a opensource gammainv function.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the function inside a call to `IFERROR` like so:

```
=IFERROR(GAMMAINV(P,alpha,beta),GAMMAINV(P,alpha,beta))
```

The problem is that Excel's `GAMMAINV` AND `GAMMA.INV` functions use an iterative algorithm which terminates is the solution does not converge within a set number of iterations. `GAMMAINV` must converge within [100 iterations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GAMMAINV-function-06393558-37ab-47d0-aa63-432f99e7916d) and `GAMMA.INV` must converge within [64 iterations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GAMMA-INV-function-74991443-c2b0-4be5-aaab-1aa4d71fbb18) .

With small parameters, the algorithms converge more slowly and therefore have a higher likelihood of terminating early, i.e. with a `#Num!` value. Fortunately, by wrapping the call to `GAMMAINV` (or `GAMMA.INV`) in a call to `IFERROR`, you exponentially reduce the likelihood of non-convergence.